# password_hash not updating when submit form

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I submit my form if password fields are submitted it should update the password else if empty does not update password.

I cannot seem to get the password_hash to update very strange. I can create new users fine with it but not update there password.

**All other post are working fine update fine.**

Not sure why password not updating? How am I able to fix issue thanks in advance.

```
<?php

class Model_user extends CI_Model {

    public function edit_user($user_id, $data) {

        $data = array(
            'username' =>  $data['username'],
            'user_group_id' =>  $data['user_group_id'],
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'image' => $data['image'],
            'status' => $data['status']
        );

        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
        $this->db->update($this->db->dbprefix . 'user');

        if ($data['password']) {

            $options = [
                'cost' => 11,
                'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),
            ];

            $data = array(
                'password' => password_hash($_POST['password'], $options)
            ); 

            $this->db->set($data);
            $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
            $this->db->update($this->db->dbprefix . 'user');
        }

    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

class Users extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('admin/user/model_user');
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->get_form();
    }

    public function update() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE) {
            $this->get_form();
        } else {
            $this->model_user->edit_user($this->uri->segment(4), $_POST);
            redirect('admin/user');
        }
    }

    public function get_form() {

        $data['title'] = "Users";

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => 'Home',
            'href' => site_url('admin/dashboard')
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => "Users",
            'href' => site_url('admin/user')
        );

        $user_info = $this->model_user->get_user($this->uri->segment(4));

        if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
            $data['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        } elseif (!empty($user_info)) {
            $data['username'] = $user_info['username'];
        } else {
            $data['username'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($_POST['user_group_id'])) {
            $data['user_group_id'] = $_POST['user_group_id'];
        } elseif (!empty($user_info)) {
            $data['user_group_id'] = $user_info['user_group_id'];
        } else {
            $data['user_group_id'] = '';
        }

        $this->load->model('admin/user_group/user_group_model');

        $data['user_groups'] = $this->user_group_model->get_user_groups();

        if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
            $data['password'] = $_POST['password'];
        } else {
            $data['password'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($_POST['confirm'])) {
            $data['confirm'] = $_POST['confirm'];
        } else {
            $data['confirm'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($_POST['firstname'])) {
            $data['firstname'] = $_POST['firstname'];
        } elseif (!empty($user_info)) {
            $data['firstname'] = $user_info['firstname'];
        } else {
            $data['firstname'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($_POST['lastname'])) {
            $data['lastname'] = $_POST['lastname'];
        } elseif (!empty($user_info)) {
            $data['lastname'] = $user_info['lastname'];
        } else {
            $data['lastname'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
            $data['email'] = $_POST['email'];
        } elseif (!empty($user_info)) {
            $data['email'] = $user_info['email'];
        } else {
            $data['email'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($_POST['image'])) {
            $data['image'] = $_POST['image'];
        } elseif (!empty($user_info)) {
            $data['image'] = $user_info['image'];
        } else {
            $data['image'] = '';
        }

        $this->load->model('admin/tool/model_tool_image');

        if (isset($_POST['image']) && is_file(FCPATH . 'image/catalog/' . $_POST['image'])) {
            $data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($_POST['image'], 100, 100);
        } elseif (!empty($user_info) && $user_info['image'] && is_file(FCPATH . 'image/catalog/' . $user_info['image'])) {
            $data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($user_info['image'], 100, 100);
        } else {
            $data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize('no_image.png', 100, 100);
        }

        $data['placeholder'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize('no_image.png', 100, 100);

        if (isset($_POST['status'])) {
            $data['status'] = $_POST['status'];
        } elseif (!empty($user_info)) {
            $data['status'] = $user_info['status'];
        } else {
            $data['status'] = 0;
        }

        $this->load->view('template/user/user_form_view', $data);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't generate your own salt. Remove the line entirely as password_hash will do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at the `edit_user` function. You receive `$data` but you immediately overwrite it. Please note that you don't set a `password` key to the newly created array. Then you check `if ($data['password'])` but that will never be `true` therefore the update will never be done.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your `password_hash($_POST['password'], $options)`.
You passed `$_POST['password']` instead of `$data['password']`.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure it out I needed to create another variable out side of the if statement in my model like below and then was able to update if new password present.

**All working now.**

```
$input_password = $this->input->post('password');

if ($input_password) {
$password = password_hash($input_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

$data_password = array(
'password' => $password
); 

$this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
$this->db->update($this->db->dbprefix . 'user', $data_password);
}
```